# Using the output of .tellg() to know the position in the file.

Tags: c++

I have a downloaded C++ utility program that dies due to an error while reading an input file. Unfortunately all that it outputs is that "error at offset: 69570744324 in file"; by looking at it's source code, I found that it was actually printing out the .tellg() output there.

I don't quite understand how one can use this offset information constructively to understand the error in the input file. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: can you please post the code snippet

Comment: If this is a logical error, i.e. you don't read from the file what you expect, then just open the file in any hex editor (FAR manager, for example) and see its contents at the desired offset.

Comment: A piece of code would be usefull

Comment: It's very hard to tell in the absence of both code and data. Your best bet is to compare the file at that offset with what the code expects. BTW: What utility program and what kind of file is this? 65 GB is rather a lot for a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with a text file you can output its content starting from some offset using this simple command:

```
tail -c +offset yourfile
```

where offset starts from 1. Looking at the content of the file around given offset may help you to understand the problem. That said the offset looks suspiciously large to me, so it may not be reported correctly.

Comment: Thanks vitaut. I tried this command and I found the input file had a problem at that position. This is helpful.

Comment: Also, the file really is 80Gigs. It's a file containing DNA sequencing data. Thanks.